# Removing /Home in route for Home Controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

For Asp.Net Core 3.1 projects, how do I remove the requirement to have `/Home` in the url for actions in the `Home` controller?

I tried decorating the controller with the attribute `[Route("/")]` but it does not work.

The start up configuration is the default from Visual Studio's template:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add empty route templates to the controller and Index action:

```cs
[Route("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Privacy")]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Error")]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well for me. It even takes care of forming the correct urls in `asp-*` attributes. For example: `<form asp-controller="Home" method="post" asp-action="Init">` will generate this html: `<form method="post" action="/Init">`. If it just configuring the routes, I doubt if such things will be taken care of.